# why the value reverse to 0 when i said return render in while loop- django?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, django-models, while-loop, logic

```
def verify(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        j=int(request.POST['code'])
        # i got j from the user
        
      
        
        attempt=0
        while attempt < 3:
            b=j
            if b==pin:
                
               
                messages.success(request, 'Access granted ')
                print(attempt)
                break
        
                # // how to check it
                
                
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'The verification code is Wrong')
                attempt+=1
                print(attempt)
                print('access denied')
        # when i run return attempt will change to 0 and reverse it                
                return render(request,'verify.html')
    return render(request,'verify.html')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What do you mean by 'attempt will change to 0 and reverse it?

Comment: that is comment not code so i meant when i run it  so i want atempt=0 so when i run renturn render and the loop retrns false so i want attempt=1 then attempt=2 but my now my attempt stays only 1 or 0

Comment: The `verify` is called again each time the user enters a pin. The `attempts` variable is reset to zero each time. The loop only runs one time then returns. You need to store the `attempt` value in the session or store it in the web page so the server gets it again.